# How can i access nested key value pair through gwt dictonary

Tags: gwt

My string is  { level1:{level2:{level3:'level3'}} }

Dictionary dict= Dictionary.getDictionary("somevar");
dict.get("level1.level2.level3")

is showing missing resourse exception.

Answer (score 1):

GWT's `Dictionary` doesn't support nested associative arrays. If you need to access data stored as such you need to create an [overlay type](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html).